# numpy.array select all even elements from d-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Is there an efficient and pythonic way to select, from a d-dimensional array, all elements that have an even index, without knowing d beforehand? And all the remaining ones (i.e. all those that have at least an odd index)?

**Minimal example of the first question**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(27)).reshape((3,3,3))
a[::2,::2,::2] 
# -> array([[[ 0,  2],
#            [ 6,  8]],
#           [[18, 20],
#            [24, 26]]])
```

**Only non-pythonic way I found for d-dimensional objects, d being variable**
At least for the "all even" part, the "at least one odd" still escapes me.

```
d = 3
a = np.array(range(3**d)).reshape([3]*d)
b = a
for i in range(d):
    b = np.take(b, np.array(range(0,b.shape[i],2)), axis=i)
```

The reason why I'm asking this (that maybe has already a higher-level solution) is that I want to iteratively create a large d-dimensional object of size `(2**n+1, ..., 2**n+1)` in n steps, at each step copying the even-indexed elements from the previous steps, something like:

```
for n in range(N):
    new_array = np.zeros([2**n+1]*d)
    new_array[all_even] = old_array
    new_array[at_least_one_odd] = #something else
```

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
a[np.ix_(*[range(0,i,2) for i in a.shape])]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [813]: def even_idx(a):
     ...:     return a[np.ix_(*[range(0,i,2) for i in a.shape])]
     ...: 

In [814]: a = np.array(range(27)).reshape((3,3,3))

In [815]: np.allclose(a[::2,::2,::2], even_idx(a) )
Out[815]: True

In [816]: a = np.array(range(27*4)).reshape((3,3,3,4))

In [817]: np.allclose(a[::2,::2,::2,::2], even_idx(a) )
Out[817]: True

In [818]: a = np.array(range(27*4*5)).reshape((3,3,3,4,5))

In [819]: np.allclose(a[::2,::2,::2,::2,::2], even_idx(a) )
Out[819]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could use slice objects.

```
even = a[[slice(None, None, 2) for _ in range(a.ndim)]]
odd = a[[slice(1, None, 2) for _ in range(a.ndim)]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately when I try to run this I get some warnings and errors, the most fundamental one is that numpy has no module "slice"... although the answer by @Divakar is already satisfying for my needs (at least for the first question, I guess the second one doesn't have a satisfactory answer) could you explain the rationale behind your answer that may be useful to me for understanding? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, slice objects are Python builtins. I updated my answer. I guess it is way more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed nice! I didn't know that there was a "slice" builtin that replaces the slice : notation, this is indeed useful. Just to clarify, the second part of the question was to have the elements with at least one odd index, not all odds; in the example, there are 27 elements of which 8 even, I naively hoped for a way to get the remaining 19 (that would be necessarily flattened out, as they lose any shape). But again, the more I think about it and the more unreasonable it seems, therefore I am fully satisfied with the first part, thanks!

Comment: Looks pretty efficient to me (based on some quick runtime tests)! Nice.